# How can I pass multiple user ids for "to" field on Facebook Message API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

How can I pass multiple user ids for "to" field on Facebook Message API, no-matter how many ids are passed, the message plugin selects only one id. Is there any possibility to have multiple ids selected on recipient field ?

function facebook_send_message(to) {

```
FB.ui({
    app_id:'xxxxxxxx',
    method: 'send',
    name: "sdfds jj jjjsdj j j ",
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxaxsa',
    to:[4345445,345345,345345],
    description:'sdf sdf sfddsfdd s d  fsf s '

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

FB.ui({
    app_id:'xxxxxxxx',
    method: 'send',
    name: "sdfds jj jjjsdj j j ",
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxaxsa',
    to:"4345445,345345,345345",
    description:'sdf sdf sfddsfdd s d  fsf s '

});

?

Comment: still the script selects only the first user of the "to" array rest of the ids are not selected.